# If statement containing len() expression not executing

Tags: python, if-statement

**EDIT: This question was caused by a faulty python/IDE install. After reinstalling IDE the code worked fine.**

I'm attempting to create a simple program that prompts for a password twice, and if entered correctly twice outputs a message saying 'Password set.' Issue is it skips my first if statement stating it must be within 8-12 characters in order to be valid. Any information on why this is not working would be appreciated.

```
pswrd = input('Please choose a password: ')
if len(pswrd) < 8 or len(pswrd) > 12:
    print('The password you have chosen is invalid. Please create a password between 8-12 characters.')
else:
    pswrd2 = input('Please retype your new password for confirmation: ')
if pswrd2 == pswrd:
        print('Thank you. Your password has been set.')
else:
    print('Your two entries do not match. Please try again.')
```

The output is this;

```
Please choose a password: seven
Please retype your new password for confirmation: seven
Thank you. Your password has been set.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

as you can see it does not recognise the password is under 8 characters. Why is this?

Comment: Works fine for me. PS: you should use [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) for password inputs in Python, it's safer and hides the password on the terminal while typing it.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "It skips ...".  It would help if you explained exactly what output you get from this code, along with the sample input you used.

Comment: As a side comment, if the original password was not of the appropriate length, this code will throw an error on the second `if` statement, because `pswrd2` will be an undefined variable.

Comment: the code appears to work fine for me too.  As per @MarcoBonelli,  you should use `getpass.getpass()`....

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thank you for your advice. This is only for a university project so only the basics are required for this however

Comment: @JohnGordon Hi I've edited the post with the output - hope this makes more sense now

Comment: There's no way this code could produce that output with the input "seven".  You must be running different code.

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code. From the indentation seen in your question, you'd get a `NameError` since `pswrd2` isn't defined unless the `else` runs

Comment: @JohnGordon No this is definitely the right code. I just copy pasted from my post and its produced the same output. Very confusing

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Hi Pranav good spot. I also added a ```pswrd2 == pswrd ``` at the start of my code and nothing has changed.

Comment: All I can do is assert that this code _cannot_ produce the results that you claim.  You _must_ be running different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that need to be included:

- a while loop so that the first password is valid
- a second password into a different variable for comparison.

This might be a better version ofthe code:

```py
import getpass

proceed = False
while proceed == False:
    x = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password: ')
    if len(x) < 8 or len(x) > 12:
        print('password needs to be >8 < 12 characters')
    else:
        proceed = True

y = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password check: ')


if x == y:
    print('this is good')
else:
    print('passwords do not match')
```

Comment: @tdelaney.  updated to 4 spaces.  (i tend to use fewer when nesting is required).

Comment: This helps thanks a lot! Do you have any idea why it wasn't working in my code? Coding is new to me so any advice is appreciated

Comment: Hi I've just ran your code and it works fine but it still allows the password even if it isn't between 8-12 characters. I don't understand how to prevent this.

Comment: @slugcat,   how?   you could literally test this out by adding `print('length is:', len(x))` inside the `if` statement....

Comment: Hi, I've ran my code in another IDE and it works perfectly. I do not understand whats happened to my PyCharm but it is fundamentally broken. This seems to be the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @slugcat,  you are welcome.  please accept the answer if it resolved the problem as this helps other users too.